# How to import non-anaconda packages

Tags: python, anaconda

I have anaconda python installed and it works great. However, occasionally I'd like to use my native python. If a run a file with `/usr/bin/python file.py`, any imports in the file are done from the anaconda package folder.

Even if I run `/usr/bin/python` to drop my self in the python console, and then try `import packagename`, the package is imported from the anaconda folder on my machine. I verified this by typing `help(packagename)`and looking at the FILE attribute.

How do I run my script using the native non-anaconda version of python and packages?

Comment: What's the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`?

Answer (score 0):

So python looks at the environmental variable PYTHONPATH to find the location of the Python packages. Change PYTHONPATH so that it points to where you have your non-Anaconda packages installed. PYTHONPATH is searched in order, so just make sure the location is before the Anaconda package install location.

You can do this by doing something like `PYTHONPATH="/new/location:${PYTHONPATH}"` depending on the shell you're using.

Alternatively, you can set PYTHONPATH within Python, so if you don't want to make the change permanent, you can do that.